# Is there any byte sequence that will never occur at the end of an gzip byte sequence

Tags: c#, bluetooth, gzip

I have a byte array representing a gzipped json array. I send this array in chunks (up to 20 bytes) over a Bluetooth connection to another device. To indicate a start of a new transmission, I send some "reset bytes" (a sequence indicating that we have a new transmission) to the other device. However, for this approach to work, I would need to make sure that the reset bytes are unique in the sense that the gzipped and chunked json array would not contain the same sequence.

The following snipped shows a shortened version of the code I use:

```
//the sequence I choose as reset sequence
var nullByteSeq = new byte[3] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
//send the reset sequence to device
var reseted = await characteristic.Write(nullByteSeq);


//messageJson is gzipped json format of a message
var messageJson = BluetoothHelper.GetMessageJson(message);

//header: first 10 bytes: message name - byte 10 to 19: message size
var header = BluetoothHelper.GetMessageHeader(message);
var written = await characteristic.Write(header);

while (bytesSentCounter < messageJson.Count()) {
    var toSend = messageJson.Skip(bytesSentCounter).Take(mtu).ToArray();
    var sent = await characteristic.Write(toSend);

    bytesSentCounter += toSend.Count();
}
```

As you can see I use three 0x00 bytes as "reset bytes". However, in some cases the messageJson is in such a format, that the last chunk sent has exactly three 0x00 bytes.

Therefore my question: Is there any kind of byte sequence that will never occur at the end of an gzip byte sequence? And if not, how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: The traditional way to do this is just send the length of the gzip data and when you've received that many bytes you know the transmission is over.

Comment: What if the app that sends the data crashes before completing the sequence? A second request would not be recognized as such, since the first message of the second request containing the message size would just be handled as part of the first message, I think. Do I miss something here?

Comment: I know nothing about bluetooth, but if it's anything like regular TCP sockets, then if the client crashes then you'll get an exception or error code or something and can't receive anymore. At that point you just perform cleanup and wait for a new connection.

Comment: Hm, although its a little bit different to regular TCP sockets, I might listen to the disconnect event of the bluetooth connection. However, I would prefer a solution that sends some kind of reset bytes, since I had some trouble with connection events not being raised in my application. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if you're receiving data from 2 different users shouldn't even be possible to conflate the data since it will be coming from 2 different contexts. Again I know nothing about bluetooth but if a person disconnects and reconnects does it just continue to read from the one stream?

Comment: The application is build in such a way that a bluetooth connection is established and hold on to when and as long as the the two devices are in range, regardless of whether there are transactions going on or not. I can send up to 20 bytes to a characteristic per transmission. If I want to send more, I have to handle that myself.  So there is no stream in the background on a lower level, just me sending up to 20 bytes to a characteristic. On a disconnect I would have to reset everything manually - if I can catch the event. Multiple users is not an issue

Comment: Yeah that could be tricky. Base64 encode the gzip data maybe? Would make it so that it can no longer contain 0x00 characters but might inflate the size a little.

Comment: For just gzipped file you can find such sequence, but for gzip _chunk_ - it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question, no. The end of a gzip stream is the number of uncompressed bytes represented in the last gzip member, modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, in little-endian order. So for long enough inputs, the last four bytes can be anything. The four bytes before that is the CRC-32 of the uncompressed data, so the last eight bytes can be anything. Before that is compressed data, and that can be anything as well for a few thousand bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Name McChange I was able to solve this problem.

As pointed out by him I used base64 encode to remove 0x00 bytes from the gzip bytes array. However instead of base64 encoding the whole byte array, I just encoded the last three bytes of that array. This is sufficient, since the confusion described in the question can only occur when the last three bytes of the gzip array are 0x00 and the array is chunked in such a way, that the last write transmission contains only three bytes.

I post this answer in the hope that it might help someone.